# Updating a <video> 's src dynamically doesn't change video

Tags: html, angular

I have an array of attachments, and I have a function that navigates through them and displays/plays the video based on its source URL. I have the URL updating correctly, but the actual video output on the site doesn't change.

Here's a minimal example HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isVideo; then videoFile; else notVideoFile"></ng-container>

<ng-template #videoFile>
  <video controls autoplay>
    <source [src]="currentAttachment.url"/>
  </video>
</ng-template>
```

I know for sure the URL updates because when I print it `{{ currentAttachment.url }}`, it's fine. The URL updates but the actual video doesn't.

Comment: can you post your iteration code here?how you set currentAttachment

Comment: just too be safe make sure you use `[src]="currentAttachment?.url"` also

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. When iterating through my attachments array I added the following code to update the src:

```
    if (this.isVideo) {
      if (this.videoFileContainer) {
        this.videoFileContainer.nativeElement.load();
        this.videoFileContainer.nativeElement.play()
      }
    }
```

and added the viewchild:

```
@ViewChild('videoFileContainer', { static: false }) videoFileContainer;
```

and then update the HTML:

```
<ng-template #videoFile>
  <video #videoFileContainer controls autoplay>
    <source [src]="currentAttachment.url"/>
  </video>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<source src="{{currentAttachment.url}}" type="video/mp4" />
```

you're doing some syntax error

Comment: The syntax that OP is using is correct which is known as property binding: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with angular however I know you have to remove the video tag and re remake the video tag with new src

Answer (score 0):

this works for me,

`<ng-template #videoFile> <video [src]="currentAttachment.url" controls autoplay/> </video> </ng-template>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).